# An inplicit differentiation question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

Given that,  $$z=f(\frac{ny-mz}{nx-lz})$$
prove that ,
$$(nx-lz)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+(ny-mz)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0 $$. where $l,m,n $ are constants .
In my notebook , it is given that
$$\frac{\partial} {\partial x}\frac{ny-mz}{nx-lz} = (ny-mz)*\frac {-n}{(nx-lz)^2}$$  which seems incorrect to me as the numerator contains $z$ which itself depends on $x$.My question is , how do i then compute $\frac{\partial} {\partial x}\frac{ny-mz}{nx-lz}$ ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What have you tried? Please include in question or it will likely be closed.

Comment: Slow down here. So $z$ is indeed defined by an implicit relation. So I agree with your complaint. This seems to be utter nonsense. Moreover, are we to assume that $l,m,n$ are all constants?

Comment: Yes , i should have mentioned that. $l,m,n$ are constants .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion is true provided the LHS of your equation is **zero**, not $z$. Suppose
$$f\left(\frac{ny-mz}{nx-lz}\right)=0\tag1$$ where $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. Writing $$u(x,y,z):= \frac{ny-mz}{nx-lz},\tag2$$ we differentiate (1) with respect to $x$ and $y$ using the chain rule to obtain
$$
\def\pard#1#2{\frac{\partial{#1}}{\partial{#2}}}
f'(u)\left(\pard ux+\pard uz\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad f'(u)\left(\pard uy + \pard uz\pard zy\right)=0
$$ respectively. (Note we are treating $u$ as a function of independent $x$, $y$, $z$ when computing partial derivatives.) The expressions in parentheses equal zero, so eliminate $\partial u/\partial z$ and rearrange to get
$$\pard uy\pard zx = \pard ux\pard zy.$$ The result follows from differentiating (2) to obtain $$\pard uy=\frac {n(nx-lz)}{(nx-lz)^2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\pard ux=\frac{-n(ny-mz)}{(nx-lz)^2},$$ plugging in, and simplifying.

Comment: Thanks for taking time out and writing the answer.I guess it should be $0$ in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct approach. You have a function $F(x,y,z)=0$ which defines $z$ implicitly as a function of $x,y$. In your case $F(x,y,z) = f(\dfrac{ny-mz}{nx-lz}) - z$.

Assuming this equation defines $z$ as a function of $x,y$, differentiate the function $\Phi(x,y)=F(x,y,z(x,y))$, which is identically $0$, with respect to $x$ and $y$ using the chain rule.

Comment: I solved it just now in my notebook but this doesn't lead to the part that is to be proved.

Comment: You should edit your post to include your attempt at a correct solution. The equation in your notebook you posted is the derivative assuming $x,y,z$ independent.

Comment: I will include a correct attempt in a few moments . I just wanted to clarify this , that even if it is not given that $x,y,z$ are independent , since $z$ depends on $x,y$ , $z$ is not independent with respect to $x$ and $y$ in the first place ?

Comment: If you do the problem as I suggested, you treat $x,y,z$ as independent when you differentiate $F$, not when you differentiate $\Phi$. This is an important distinction.